# How can I build my solution through TFS online portal if I have to implement .Net CLI?

Tags: powershell, tfs, asp.net-core, .net-core-rc2, dnvm

The project was using DNVM powershell script to install it on TFS but now as it got obsolete and the url https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aspnet/Home/dev/dnvminstall.ps1 returned as 404 not found. Now the need is to migrate it from DNVM to .Net Core and I was unable to find the exact solution how I can write a powershell script for installing .Net Core. Please help

Also If I tried skipping the DNVM installation task from Build definition then it throws below error:

> The "GetBuildOptions" task was not given a value for the required parameter "RuntimeToolingDirectory".

Comment: I haven't tried it, but, may be this is the equivalent https://github.com/dotnet/cli/blob/rel/1.0.0/scripts/obtain/dotnet-install.ps1

Comment: How did you build the project locally？Could you build successfully if you skip the DNVM installation locally?